# MSSQL - Declutter report, replace duplicate values in a column -> SPACE or QOUTATIONMARK

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a report that sometimes lists a lot of repeeting data.
I have made an example below, 
I don't want to change the table, only the result from my SELECT-statement, so it gets displayed like the example to the right (not yellow).

[image]

This is something that can be done in Excel but that I do not know how to do in MySQL. Maybee someone can point me in the right direction.

The most tricky part here is the line no 4 ("B","E"), but even if only Column1 can work in an easy way it will make the report a lot less messy.

DESTINCT is not the thing I whant to achive, I whant the row to remaine (shown in yellow) but to put a qoutationsign or maybe a "space", when the row abowe is the same, and in the little more advanced case when 2 columns are the same, as showned in "Column2" in the "E-case".

I imagine that some INNER JOIN might help, and a (CASE WHEN THEN END) might do the trick.

Maybee some counting like ROW_NUMBER and ROW_NUMBER-1 as well.

To create the table in my example:

```
CREATE TABLE mila_test (
    Column1 VARCHAR(1),
    Column2 VARCHAR(1),
    Value INT
)
```

To populate it:

```
INSERT INTO mila_test
VALUES 
    ('A','D','1'),
    ('A','D','2'),
    ('A','E','3'),
    ('B','E','4'),
    ('B','E','5'),
    ('B','F','6'),
    ('B','F','7'),
    ('C','F','8'),
    ('C','G','9')
```

I do not have any advance SQL like T-SQL.

Comment: SQL is not designed to do that. I can be done but it shouldn't and is not that easy,. Such things should handle your program logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `lag()` window function:

```
select
  case 
    when column1 = lag(column1) over (order by column1, column2) then '"' 
    else column1 
  end col1,
  case when column1 = lag(column1) over (order by column1, column2) then 
    case 
      when column2 = lag(column2) over (order by column1, column2) then '"' 
      else column2 
    end 
    else column2
  end col2,
  value
from mila_test
order by column1, column2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/euFc3UtHMdNerShX22gh6u/1).
Or with `row_number()`:

```
with cte as (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by column1 order by column2) rn1,
    row_number() over (partition by column1, column2 order by column2) rn2
  from mila_test
)
select 
  case when rn1 = 1 then column1 else '"' end col1,
  case when rn2 = 1 then column2 else '"' end col2,
  value
from cte
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/euFc3UtHMdNerShX22gh6u/3).
[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8c118b1a99f924d84e68fee1f5d4d32c) for SQL Server.
Results:

```
| col1 | col2 | value |
| ---- | ---- | ----- |
| A    | D    | 1     |
| "    | "    | 2     |
| "    | E    | 3     |
| B    | E    | 4     |
| "    | "    | 5     |
| "    | F    | 6     |
| "    | "    | 7     |
| C    | F    | 8     |
| "    | G    | 9     |
```

Comment: Thank you, amazing it worked and I have a lot of new stuff to try to understand. The OVER and PARTITION BY, I will have to dive into deeper, and I had no ide it existed. It worked out fine on my simple SQL.

Comment: Check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 and https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-t-sql-window-functions/

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables inside the query and assign to them the current row values:

```
SELECT
    IF(m.COLUMN1 = @c1, '"', m.COLUMN1) AS COLUMN1,
    IF(m.COLUMN1 = @c1 AND m.COLUMN2 = @c2, '"', m.Column2) AS COLUMN2,
    m.`value`,
    @c1 := m.COLUMN1 AS c1_var,
    @c2 := m.Column2 AS c2_var
FROM 
    mila_test m
ORDER BY 
    m.`value`
```

Output:

```
+---------+---------+-------+--------+--------+
| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | value | c1_var | c2_var |
+---------+---------+-------+--------+--------+
| A       | D       |     1 | A      | D      |
| "       | "       |     2 | A      | D      |
| "       | E       |     3 | A      | E      |
| B       | E       |     4 | B      | E      |
| "       | "       |     5 | B      | E      |
| "       | F       |     6 | B      | F      |
| "       | "       |     7 | B      | F      |
| C       | F       |     8 | C      | F      |
| "       | G       |     9 | C      | G      |
+---------+---------+-------+--------+--------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Nice one but I can not use T-SQL only kind of MySQL syntax, and my MySQL woun't accept an IF-statement. It then trows this at me:

SqlState  37000 Native 156
 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'...

Comment: @MichaelLarsson, your title contains MySQL, but not MSSQL. IF statement is a native part of supported SQL in MySQL database. What kind of database you are using? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17de53/1

Comment: It is "Database version: Microsoft SQL Server, version 11.00.3128", but it is kind of two parts to it. I use a test database offcourse but it is much moore easy for me to try stuff out in one part of the client. I can se results at once there, wich makes development much faster there, but it is some what a lot more ristricted what I can do there, compared to in the other parts. Exempel in the other part I can do COPY TO FILE. It is some kind of SQL dialect, but both of Forpas's examples worked right out of the box.